# How can I create a code with Javascript which Automatically click buttons on a web site

Tags: javascript, html

How can I create a code with Javascript which Automatically click buttons and writing in texbutton and click checkbutton same time on a web site. If I do that, it will be very helpful for me.

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<a href="index.html" class="wp_textBox">Giris</a>
</body>
<script src=" My_Link_ "></script> 
<script type="text/javascript">
 window.onload = function() {
  window.location.href = ('.wp_textBox').attr('href');
});
}
</script>

</html>
```

Actully I can't create already code, its not working. To understand what I want actually.

On web site, we have text button, select button, checkbox and search button together, in the first we can use textbox with same code (we can wirte same text in text button in the first). It is enough. But I need to write some thing in this text button for searching. After that, for this searching, I need to click chechbuttun (A5) for classify. Last thing that I want is click search button (text button has writen, select button already clicked, checkbox already clicked).

How can I do that? Which way I need to follow clearly? Is there a somebody has example application with java script?

Empty Screen [Input Screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U4GOt.png)

I want to do that I such as this picture automatically. [Final Project that I want](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sJMjN.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

add id attribute to your anchor

```
 <a href="index.html" class="wp_textBox" id="girls">Giris</a>
```

modify the script tag like this.

```
window.onload = function() {
  document.getElementById('girls').click();
});
}
```

**EDIT**

To fill text field from js, just add ID attribute with `txtAuthDocNumber` name to your text field and write below code

```
document.getElementsById("txtAuthDocNumber").innerHTML="00VF832A";
```

For Select Option

```
document.getElementById('txtAuthDocNumberSelect').value="00VF832A";
```

For Check Box

```
document.getElementById("check_box_id").checked = true
```

To Click on button

```
 document.getElementById('button_id').click();
```

Comment: As I shared Input Screen's Picture, after modify my code with your comment still empyt. I want to write some text in this "textbutton" and I want to wirte code for click search button automatically. How can it possible?